# send form data with rtk query

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I wanna send an image with form data to the nest js server with RTK query but the file didn't send. the code are:

```
    uploadImage: builder.mutation<any, any>({
  query: (imageFile) => {
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('file', imageFile);
    console.log({ bodyFormData, imageFile });
    return {
      url: '/uploader/image',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
      },
      body: { bodyFormData }
    };
  }
})
```

I can send an image with Axios but in RTK I cant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also pass another **parameter called formData** **in RTK Query** while passing formdata in API request.

```
  uploadImage: builder.mutation<any, any>({
  query: (imageFile) => {
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('file', imageFile);
    console.log({ bodyFormData, imageFile });
    return {
      url: '/uploader/image',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
      },
      body: { bodyFormData },
      formData:true           //add this line 
    };
  }
})
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename') still get error

Comment: `Content-Type` should be omitted from `headers` because it's added automatically with the correct boundary if `formData` is `true`.

Comment: That prop `formData: true` doesn't exist anymore. Adding `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `body: { bodyFormData }` instead use `body: bodyFormData`.

Additionally, you could try using this structure:

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('file', {
      uri: imageFileUri, 
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: imageFileUri?.split('/')[imageFileUri?.split('/').length - 1]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sending the FormData directly on the `body` works for me. No need to manually set the header (it will be set for you) nor adding `formData: true`.

Example:

```
    uploadImage: builder.mutation<any, any>({
      query: (imageFile) => {
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append('file', imageFile);
        console.log({ bodyFormData, imageFile });
        return {
          url: '/uploader/image',
          method: 'POST',
          body: bodyFormData
        };
      }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, adding `"Accept", "application/json"` in addition to `formData: true` solved the problem.

Comment: `formData: true` Doesn't exist anymore.